# How to make a spring effect in AndEngine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I am new to android. I want to make a spring sort of thing in AndEngine just like we see in classic pinball how can we achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Rajeel, you can use Prismatic Joint for this purpose. Its movement is fixed along a single axis. I used Prismatic Joint for this and it worked fine for me.